# Randomness vs Uniqueness?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, random, unique

In a web application if a user check the `Remember Me` box I'm gonna create a cookie and save it in database and assign it to user (long-life cookie). On any page request (page_load) I check this cookie (if session is null) and ask DAL for user object.
If I use GUID it would be unique but the question is if a user can guess the pattern maybe he could cheat by sending a hand-made cookie.
What is the best practice (C# sample) for creating such a text to be random enough ?

Comment: title is not an accurate description of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx)** method (even if you don't use Forms authentication). There's no point in reinventing the wheel ;-)

Comment: Then how to retrieve it and store it in database ?

Comment: By calling FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie. Or better use ASP.NET session id (HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID)